# I am getting multiple records per individual when I only want one per individual in my SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table that has eligible students in it. Each student can be eligible multiple time therefore they can be in the table multiple times. My goal is to pull only one student record per student that meet the criteria. I am using a very basic query

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                chp_id, 
                MEM_LNAME, 
                MEM_FNAME, 
                EmailAddress, 
                PRESENTMEM, 
                Refused
           FROM EligmemList
          WHERE ((FORMYEAR = 2019 and FORMSEMESTER = 4) OR
                (FORMYEAR = 2020 and FORMSEMESTER = 2))
```

Of course when I use several values in a distinct I am going to get multiple records per eligible student if there are any differences. Anyone have any ideas?

Current Results
id     chp_id   MEM_LNAME   MEM_FNAME   EmailAddress PRESENTMEM   Refused
1479418 31    Aaeng                     Aaro         N            N
1482412 135   Aafedt        Brian       bria         N            N
1538460 135   Aafedt        Brian       bria         Y            N
1495908 115   Aamer         Zara        za37         N            Y
1556465 54    Aamer         Zain        zaam         N            N
1558558 115   Aamer         Zara        za37         Y
1513073 17    Aanderud      Erika       Eriku        N            N
1568116 17    Aanderud      Erika       Eriku        N            N
1488528 45    Aaron         Brooke      baar         N            N
1510872 152   Aaron         Dominick    ajd6         N            N
1511112 152   Aaron         Payne       atp5         N            N
1543882 158   Aaron         Curtis      caar         N            N
1573377 45    Aaron         Brooke      baar         N            Y
1562018 216   Aarons        Andrew      aa18         N            N
1507647 212   Aaronson      Jacob       jaar         N            N
1552699 212   Aaronson      Jacob       jaar         Y            NULL

Expected results

id     chp_id   MEM_LNAME   MEM_FNAME   EmailAddress PRESENTMEM   Refused
1479418 31      Aaeng                   Aaro         N            N
1538460 135     Aafedt      Brian       bria         Y            N
1556465 54      Aamer       Zain        zaam         N            N
1558558 115     Aamer       Zara        za37         Y
1568116 17      Aanderud    Erika       Eriku        N            N
1488528 45      Aaron       Brooke      baar         N            N
1510872 152     Aaron       Dominick    ajd6         N            N
1511112 152     Aaron       Payne       atp5         N            N
1543882 158     Aaron       Curtis      caar         N            N
1573377 45      Aaron       Brooke      baar         N            Y
1562018 216     Aarons      Andrew      aa18         N            N
1552699 212     Aaronson    Jacob       jaar         Y            NULL

Hopefully I am getting the most recent record from the ones that are duplicates.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  You have no columns that are "eligible" or "students" so it is really hard to apply the explanation to the query.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: SQL is a language not a database, tag your DB please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `GROUP BY` command:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS Id,
            MIN(chp_id) as chp_Id, 
            MEM_LNAME, 
            MEM_FNAME, 
            EmailAddress, 
            MIN(PRESENTMEM) AS PresentMem, 
            MIN(Refused) AS Refused
FROM EligmemList
WHERE ((FORMYEAR = 2019 and FORMSEMESTER = 4) OR
            (FORMYEAR = 2020 and FORMSEMESTER = 2))
GROUP BY
            MEM_LNAME, 
            MEM_FNAME, 
            EmailAddress
```

Any fields in the `Select` portion that are not included in the `Group by` need to be in "Aggregate" functions such as `MAX(...)`

Included the fields that define "Uniqueness" in the `Group By`. That is, what do you want to return if someone enters the same email address but different first and last names? If you want those returned as separate records, include all three in `Group By` as in the example above.

Comment: I think that is getting what I want. There still could be duplicates when a person has two different email addresses. Ideally I would like to get the most recent record for each person.